# Transfer multiple files and folder to a Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

I have storage that's where I host a static website. I want to create a task that transfers my build files into that storage.

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $env:prSourceBranchName -StorageAccountKey "e4Nt0i1pcsYWnzLKw4PRdwu+************/qMj7fXyJK6lS4YTlPCOdbFlEG2LN9g2i5/yQ=="
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build    
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build ls -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $env:prSourceBranchName -Context $context
```

When I run the code:

[image]

I can see the files that need to be uploaded but when I check my `$web` blob (created by the Static Website) it's empty.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0 check out the second example.

Can someone explain why nothing is happening?

I want to do this > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch but through AzureRM.

Comment: Hi Peter, if the answer below works for you, could you please help mark it as answer? it would be helpful for others. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ls` from your last line of code which is used to upload to blob storage:

Change:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build ls -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $env:prSourceBranchName -Context $context
```

To:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $env:prSourceBranchName -Context $context
```

Comment: I also want to share that if you have issues with the `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` not doing anything you should also check your storage key! Mine was incorrect at some point and there's no feedback that was the problem.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, thanks for the sharing. For "no feedback for incorrect storage key", if you can see the output, you should see the error message says 403 forbidden.

Comment: That's not the case though. When I use the wrong storage key there's no error message, no output at all. It's like the function isn't running.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, how about add `-ErrorAction Stop` at then end of the cmdlet `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`?